# GeoServer on access antivirus scanning exclusions

Tags: geoserver

The powers that be have decided to implement on-access virus scanning on all servers - i.e. a file is scanned each time it's accessed, unless it's on an exclusion list, and I've been asked to come up with the exclusion list - just ask the supplier, they say.
One of the servers is running GeoServer, and there is no supplier.

Files accessed at GeoServer start aren't really a problem. It's those that will be accessed during normal map serving, and which will cause response times to suffer that I'm worried about (I've got all the mapping data covered)

Has anyone any clue about where I could find the info?

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer will mostly be reading data during normal operations so that will be fine. For completeness you can probably exclude all of the data directory too. In an ideal world you wouldn't be running on a windows box so that you get memory mapped file buffers for speed too.

Note, you can buy [commercial support](http://geoserver.org/support/) for GeoServer from several companies (including my employer).